# probing privatePath and subdirectories

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution

In my application I would like to put DLL files in a subdirectory. I'm using the `probing` element in app.config and it works quite fine, but I've got an issue with localization assemblies.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="libs"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

If I have two DLLs in:

```
libs/de/myAssembly.dll
```

and

```
libs/myAssembly.dll
```

The first one is loaded, while I want that the file in the root folder is preferred. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I discovered that the problem was related only to resources' dll and to the way I was implementing the AssemblyResolve event handler. Now I test the cultureInfo before I load the assembly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set multiple paths to probe.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="libs;libs/de;libs/fr"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Please see official microsoft documentation on [probing element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Read the comment to my own question. Thank you.

Comment: Just a random programmer passing by saying thank you for your solution ^_^